# Privoxy/TOR not working with Iceweasel

Tags: firefox, proxy, tor, http-proxy

I installed tor and privoxy on my linux 64-bit box. And uncommented the following line in /etc/privoxy/config file.

```
        forward-socks5   /               127.0.0.1:9050 .
```

Then I started services for both. Now, if I run either of the following commands, I get the same IP address, which is not the real ip of PC. So I conclude both tor and privoxy are running.

```
curl -x 127.0.0.1:8118 curlmyip.com
curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 curlmyip.com
```

If I use chrome with `--proxy-server localhost:8118` switch, I again get the same anonymized IP address.

The problem is, I cannot use the http proxy, localhost 8118, with firefox/iceweasel. I go to Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Network -> Settings and set HTTP and SSL proxies to localhost 8118. Iceweasel says "The proxy server is refusing connections"

Any solutions?

Comment: It turns out blacklisting ipv6 helps.

Comment: though, I assume a real answer should exist.

Comment: see my answer below. perhaps that is the real answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The use of browsers other than Tor Browser is [recommended against](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/WebBrowsers). The use of privoxy / polipo has been deprecated by The Tor Project long time ago as well. The current advice is to only use [Tor Browser](https://torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en), because only Tor Browser gives you an unified web fingerprint and you won't stand out.

Comment: Good point, I should have said that too.  I voted you up because your answer is the most important point to make.  But the poster was specifically asking something else, so I answered his specific question.

The real reason to use the Tor Browser Bundle is however because people who try to do it themselves (as this poster is doing), usually don't do it correctly and end up leaking DNS or some other information.  The Tor developers got sick of trying to help everyone with their roll-your-own setups, so they decided to do it once correctly and just support that.

Comment: By the way, you might want to change the spelling of _advice_.  I tried to do it for you, but edits must be at least six characters, and there is only one character in your answer that should be changed. :)

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar error where I was trying to use a combination of tor and privoxy on home PC.

The OS used was Kali Linux 2.0.

**Steps to replicate issue**

Installed tor

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

Started Tor relay

```
tor
```

Validated if tor was working

```
netstat -atnp tor | egrep tor
```

In the output, observed tor output -- great.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2401/tor        
tcp        0      0 192.168.x.x:44278       xx.xxx.xx.xx:443        ESTABLISHED 2401/tor
```

Installed privoxy

```
sudo apt-get install privoxy
```

Modified default privoxy config file in /etc/privoxy/config as per the instructions [here](http://www.privoxy.org/faq/misc.html) under "*How do I use privoxy together with tor*" and included the following lines:

```
forward-socks4a 127.0.0.1:9050   .
forward         192.168.*.*/     .
forward            10.*.*.*/     .
forward           127.*.*.*/     .
```

Then started privoxy

```
privoxy /etc/privoxy/config
```

Ran the command to check if privoxy was working:

```
netstat -atnp | egrep privoxy
```

Output showed that privoxy was running (Notice tcp6 which is IPv6 -  I didn't pay attention to that initially, **but this was the problem**):

```
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8118                :::*                    LISTEN      3881/privoxy
```

Then set the SSL and HTTP proxy to 127.0.0.1:8118 and I got the error when surfing internet sites, "The proxy chosen is refusing connections"

**Fix:**

On reading the privoxy config file carefully, the listen-address stanza displays the following information.

```
Some operating systems will prefer IPv6 to IPv4 addresses even
if the system has no IPv6 connectivity which is usually not
expected by the user. Some even rely on DNS to resolve
localhost which mean the "localhost" address used may not
actually be local.

**It is therefore recommended to explicitly configure the
intended IP address instead of relying on the operating
system, unless there's a strong reason not to.**
```

Appears that KALI was preferring to bind to the IPv6 localhost [::1] than IPv4 local host 127.0.0.1 even though I had no IPv6 connectivity.

So I changed listen-address line from

```
listen-address localhost:8118
```

to

```
listen-address 127.0.0.1:8118
```

and restarted privoxy...

```
pkill privoxy  # kills all processes with privoxy in their name
privoxy /etc/privoxy/config
```

I then set the SSL, HTTP proxies to 127.0.0.1:8118 and the SOCKS proxy to 127.0.0.1:9050 (Socks 4) in ICEWEASEL. And voila! I was able to connect to internet sites.

For verification, I ran netstat and nmap which showed that privoxy was binding to IPv4 localhost IP..

```
> netstat -atnp | grep privoxy
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8118          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3934/privoxy

> nmap 127.0.0.1 -p 8118 
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8118/tcp open  privoxy

> nmap -6 localhost -p 8118 
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8118/tcp closed  privoxy
```

**Note:**
My /etc/hosts file also has the entry for the localhost: 
127.0.0.1   localhost

Comment: Still very useful in 2022. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.  Please try downloading a binary version of Firefox:

ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/17.0.8esr/linux-i686/en-US/

Following your exact instructions above with this binary on Gentoo worked for me.  I'd surmise that you have an off version of Firefox.